# Fancybox navigation arrows and close button do not have transparent hover

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-2

Using fancybox 2.1.5 in wordpress, when I hover over the left or right side of the pic, I always get a grey overlay instead of the regular transparent one.

Can someone take a look, what has gone wrong?

http://homesweet.homelinux.org/wordpress/index.php/2013/09/06/mindennapok-25/
(just click any of the pics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it's not a good idea to set css rules to global elements but use specificity instead.

You have this css rule in the line 62 of your [style.css](http://homesweet.homelinux.org/wordpress/wp-content/themes/open-sourcerer/style.css) file :

```
a {
    color: #DCDAD5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

That rule affects to all `<a>` anchors, including fancybox (nav arrows) anchors.

Try changing it into something like

```
a.myclass {
    color: #DCDAD5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or target the parent like

```
#parent a {
    color: #DCDAD5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

so it will only affect to the elements it should.

Comment: That's good advice. Sadly I've inherited this style but after this I definitely learned never to do this.
Turns out the problem was not the text-decoration, but the a:hover's background property that cleared the transparent property of fancybox's hover (that was left undefined, thus wordpress' theme has overwritten its style).